# What was the first original purpose of the nLocktime? Was it only the time bound to nSequence?

Tags: locktime, sequence

Pieter Wuille gave an amazing [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/120274/145749) related to the connection between nSequence and nLocktime in the early days of Bitcoin.

However, based on his answer it looks like the `nLocktime` **was NOT really originally intended just for the absolute time lock** in sense `you cannot include this transaction in the blockchain before the UTC timestamp/block height defined in nLocktime pass`.

As I understood, `nLocktime` was more intended to work together with the `nSequence` as a time bound in sense **how much time we will wait in mempool for the transaction to become final in context of replacing**, than to be just absolute time lock. If we want our transaction to immediately become "final" (ready for the blockchain) then we just need to set all `nSequence` to 0xffffffff. **Since there will be no replacement**, there is no need to wait for anything, so the `nLocktime` value is ignored. Also, we can set `nLocktime` to zero and since **we don't wait any time for the replacement**, in this case the transaction also becomes immediately "final" regardless of the value of `nSequence`.

So I would say that the `nLocktime` is originally intended to be the time in which we will wait for a replacement. However, as we can set the `nSequence` to, for example, `0xfffffffe` and never increase it and set the `nLocktime` to some time (UTC timestamp/block height), then the `nLocktime` indirectly becomes, and can be used, as the absolute timelock.

As addition. It doesn't work that way today. This relationship between the `nSequence` value and the `nLocktime` value still remained as a consensus rule (would require hard fork to change), so if all `nSequence`s are 0xffffffff, then the `nLocktime` value is not considered, and otherwise `nLocktime` can be used as an absolute timelock. However, replacement today has nothing to do with `nSequence` (it just must be less than 0xffffffff-1 and that is all), nor wait for `nLocktime` time.

What do you think? What was the first original purpose of the `nLocktime`? Am I right?

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116706/13866 re Nakamoto email on this subject in 2011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `RedGrittyBrick's` [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/116722/145749) and an email Satoshi sent to  Mike Hearn, it appears that the original purpose of `nLocktime` was indeed as a time bound for replacement and was not intended to be absolute time lock. Since it was never properly implemented, `nLocktime` is now used as absolute time lock with any `nSequence` set to a value less than `0xffffffff`.

So I confirm what I wrote in the question.

I thank `RedGrittyBrick` once again for his help.